# Eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^\top\mathbf{A}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

**1. Background**

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ with $M\le N$ and $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^\top =\mathbf{I}_M$, I study some properties of $\mathbf{A}^\top \mathbf{A}$. Especially, I found that it always have $M$ eigenvalues close to $1$.

In my experiments, I write the following Python code based on PyTorch framework:

```
import torch

X = torch.randn(10, 10)
U, S, V = torch.linalg.svd(X)
A = (U @ V)[:5]  # create an orthonormal matrix
print(torch.linalg.eigvals(A.t() @ A))
```

One output is:

```
tensor([3.0804e-08+0.j, 5.8120e-08+0.j, 2.1118e-10+0.j, 1.0000e+00+0.j, 1.0000e+00+0.j,
        1.0000e+00+0.j, 1.0000e+00+0.j, 1.0000e+00+0.j, 4.8640e-08+0.j, 7.6686e-09+0.j])
```

We can see that there are $M=5$ eigenvalues close to $1$.

---

**2. Question**

Does always $M$ eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^\top \mathbf{A}$ be $1$? How to show that?

Comment: When you say "orthonormal matrix", do you mean an "orthogonal matrix", i.e. a matrix with orthonormal columns? Saying $\mathbf{A}$ is orthogonal (when $\mathbf{A}$ is real) is equivalent to saying $\mathbf{A}^\top \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}$, so all the eigenvalues ought to be *exactly* $1$. Perhaps this is just rounding error?

Comment: For any matrix to be orthogonal, it must be square

Comment: @VictorSouza Not in every definition I've seen. Some allow "tall" matrices consisting of orthonormal columns, or define it by $\mathbf{A}^\top \mathbf{A} = I$, rather than using inverses. Such matrices represent linear isometries from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^m$, where $m \ge n$.

Comment: @TheoBendit in that case would $\mathbf{A}^{\top}$ be $\mathbf{A}$'s Moore-Penrose inverse?

Comment: @VictorSouza Indeed it would!

Comment: @VictorSouza A question, and then its answer, crossed my mind just then: does $A^+ = A^\top$ characterise orthogonality as I've described above? The answer: no, it does not. For example, the $n \times n$ square matrix of all $1/\sqrt{n}$s is its own transpose and pseudoinverse, but is not orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m<n$ and $AA^\top=I_m$, the $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A^\top A$ is of rank $m$, and thus it has $n-m$ zero eigenvalues. At the same time, if we write $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a_1^\top \\ \vdots \\ a_m^\top\end{bmatrix},\ A^\top = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & \cdots & a_m\end{bmatrix},$$ where $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $a_i^\top a_i=1$ and $a_ia_j=0$ for $i\ne j$.

Then $a_i^\top A^\top A a_i = 1$ for all $i=1,\ldots,m$. Thus, the matrix $A^\top A$ has $m$ eigenvalues equal to 1.